# XML Path Assertion in Jmeter

Tags: java, xpath, jmeter

I want to Assert a value (`ActualCode`) in `XPath Assertions`. I am experienced with JSON Path Assertion but totally  new to XML one. How could I assert the 'ActualCode' value here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <ns2:CreateValidCode xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.net/lmsglobal/ws/v1/extint/types" xmlns="http://www.example.net/lmsglobal/xsd/v1/types" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.net/lmsglobal/ws/v1/extint/notification/types">
     <ns2:ValidCode>ActualCode</ns2:ValidCode>
     <ns2:State>1</ns2:State>
  </ns2:CreateValidCode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a *.properties* file, i.e. `namespaces.properties` somewhere, for example in JMeter.s "bin" folder.
2. Add the following lines to the *namespaces.properties* file

   ```
   S=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
   ns2=http://www.example.net/lmsglobal/ws/v1/extint/types
   ```
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file, it lives under JMeter "bin" folder as well

   ```
   xpath.namespace.config=namespaces.properties
   ```
4. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
5. Add [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns above XML
6. Tick `Use Namespaces` box
7. Put the following query into the "XPath Assertion" input:

   ```
   //ns2:ValidCode/text()='ActualCode'
   ```

That should be it.

Useful material:

- [XPath Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Demo:

[image: XPath Namespaces Demo]

Comment: Thanks! One smal related question. How to comapre the result with a variable? I tried several ways like //ns2:ValidCode/text()= $.Code but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Already figured it out! //ns2:ValidCode/text() = '${Code }' is the way to go!